# Are these two forms of relative import exactly the same?

Tags: python, python-import

```
from .. dog import Dog
```

Or:

```
from ..dog import Dog
```

Both seem to work. Any difference at all?

Comment: No. There is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference actually.

But it is better to organize them into `__init__.py`.

If you are using a `__init__.py`

- `from .. import XXX` (that is, import based on the **init**.py in the father folder.)
- `from ..A import XXX` (that is, import file A in the father folder.)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you meant. All imports should be put into init.py?

Answer (score 0):

It' The same.
Python syntax is not too strict about the spaces at the same line of code like that
for example:

```
dict='hello'
print( dict )
```

will get you the same result of

```
dict='hello'
print(dict)
```

and both of them will print hello

python is just interested in the tabs (or the 4 spaces) for the loops or the functions